# Count the length of an array

Tags: java

I having an input file
First line is the size of array(N)
Second line is N element

I have to proceeded if `N ==No of element in second line`
For EX:

```
3
1 3 4 //ok
4
3 5 6 7 7 // Do nothing
```

My code:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("ok.txt"));
int n = in.nextInt();
if(n==in.nextLine().length())
// MAke an array of element


in.nextLine().length() Is not giving me a correct length i.e 3 and 5
```

Comment: What length is it giving you? What were you expecting?

Comment: not getting what you looking for will you please explain it bit more.

Comment: System.in is use for taking input from console. As you mention in question "I having an input file". So you need to pass the FileInputStream object here with the path of a file you are talking about.

Comment: Please Post a more elaborate question

Answer (score 5):

in.nextLine() will give you a String containing :

```
"1 3 4"
```

with 2 spaces and 3 digits.
You should do :

```
String line = in.nextLine();
String[] digits = line.split(" ");
if (n==digits.length) {
    ...
```

Moreover be aware of the fact that using `in.nextLine()` in your if condition, leads you to lost the content of the line

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps with your question, assuming that I understood your question.

```
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try{
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("yourFile.txt"));
        int array_size = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        String[] array = reader.readLine().split("\\s+");
        if(array_size == array.length){
            //continue
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this code to read two lines. The method will return null if the size doesn't match, and the array otherwise.

```
public String[] readTwoLines (BufferedReader in)
{
    int length = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
    String[] ints = in.readLine().split("\\s+");
    if (ints.length == length) return ints;
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int n = in.nextInt();
if((n*2)==(in.nextLine().length()-1))
//correct length
else
//Incorrect length
```

Try the above code. In the file,if integers are seperated by spaces,then it also counts as a character in length. Subtracting one from length is because the number of spaces is one less than the number of integers. Note that the above is applicable only when n>1.